# Round numbers in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I have a function @for in SCSS for grid columns (12 columns).
My SASS function:

```
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
.lp-col.s#{$i} { width: 100%/12 * $i; }
}
```

CSS result:

```
.lp-col.l5 {
width: 41.6666666667%; }
```

And so on for all 12 columns

How can I round up the % value for example to 41.6666% ?

I use Visual Studio Code and Prepros for CSS compilation.

Comment: I think you mean trim. I don't see rounding up from `41.6666666667%` to `41.6666%`. May I ask why you want to do this? What is the issue that the former number is causing the later number fixes?

Comment: Yes, to be more precise, trim. I resolved the problem by just replacing width: 100%/12 * $i; into width: 99.99%/12 * $i;